# 特殊文字を正規表現で判定したい

Tags: php, 正規表現

**会員登録時に特殊文字の入力チェックをしたいです。**

PHPで、

```
case 'SPECIAL_CHARCTER'
if($value == ''){ //仮
  $arrErr[$key] = '※ ' . $this->disp_name[$index] . 'に特殊文字が含まれています。<br>';
}
break;
```

のifの箇所に、preg_matchを使用してHTML特殊文字のチェックを行いたいです。

調べましたが、四苦八苦しています。。

アドバイスをいただけませんか？

Comment: disp_nameて事は表示に使用する名前ですよね？許容する文字に漢字とか記号も含まれるんですか？あと、特殊文字ってどんな物を想定されていますか？

Comment: [HTML特殊文字](http://pst.co.jp/powersoft/html/index.php?f=3401) ということであれば、`if ( $value != htmlentities($value) ) { ...` で良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match('/[<>&"]/', $value))
```

とかこんな感じでしょうか。

が、このまま使わないでください。

Webアプリケーションにおいて、なぜ(あえて不正確な用語を使いますが)「HTML特殊文字」に特別な扱いが必要なのか、どのように適切に処理すべきか、というのは基本として理解が必要です。一般論としては出力時にエスケープするべきで、入力時にチェックするのは筋が悪い方法だと考えられています。

(アプリケーション要件として使える文字種を制限することはありますが、そうであればエラーメッセージはもっと適切な物にしたほうがよいでしょう)

Webアプリケーションはささいなことで簡単に脆弱性が生じ得ますので、きちんと勉強されることをお勧めします。書籍であれば、「体系的に学ぶ安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方」(ISBN: 978-4-7973-6119-3)は一通り知っておいた方がよいことが網羅されていますのでお勧めです。

Comment: `disp_name` という変数名や連結する文字列から、`$this->disp_name[$index]` には入力欄の名前が入っているような気がします。チェック対象の文字列は `$value` のようですし。

Comment: @unarist  指摘の通りコードを誤読していましたのでその点は修正しました。

Answer (score -1):

ご回答ありがとうございます。
CMSへのバリデーションの実装でしたので、条件式の挿入を行いました。
ご紹介いただいた書籍は是非読ませていただきます、丁寧にありがとうございました。

続いて報告まで、以下の配列で実装しました。。
$strings = [
    " ", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'",
    "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", ".", "/", ":", ";",
    "<", "&nvlt", "=", "&bne", ">", "&nvgt", "?",
    "@", "[", "\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "&fjlig",
    "{", "|", "}", " ", "¡", "¢", "£", "¤", "¥",
    "¦", "§", "¨", "©", "ª", "«", "¬", "­", "®",
    "¯", "°", "±", "²", "³", "´", "µ", "¶", "·",
    "¸", "¹", "º", "»", "¼", "½", "¾", "¿", "À",
    "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç", "È", "É",
    "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò",
    "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "×", "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û",
    "Ü", "Ý", "Þ", "ß", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä",
    "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í",
    "î", "ï", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö",
    "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "þ", "ÿ",
    "Ā", "ā", "Ă", "ă", "Ą", "ą", "Ć", "ć", "Ĉ",
    "ĉ", "Ċ", "ċ", "Č", "č", "Ď", "ď", "Đ", "đ",
    "Ē", "ē", "Ė", "ė", "Ę", "ę", "Ě", "ě", "Ĝ",
    "ĝ", "Ğ", "ğ", "Ġ", "ġ", "Ģ", "Ĥ", "ĥ", "Ħ",
    "ħ", "Ĩ", "ĩ", "Ī", "ī", "Į", "į", "İ", "ı",
    "Ĳ", "ĳ", "Ĵ", "ĵ", "Ķ", "ķ", "ĸ", "Ĺ", "ĺ",
    "Ļ", "ļ", "Ľ", "ľ", "Ŀ", "ŀ", "Ł", "ł", "Ń",
    "ń", "Ņ", "ņ", "Ň", "ň", "ŉ", "Ŋ", "ŋ", "Ō",
    "ō", "Ő", "ő", "Œ", "œ", "Ŕ", "ŕ", "Ŗ", "ŗ",
    "Ř", "ř", "Ś", "ś", "Ŝ", "ŝ", "Ş", "ş", "Š",
    "š", "Ţ", "ţ", "Ť", "ť", "Ŧ", "ŧ", "Ũ", "ũ",
    "Ū", "ū", "Ŭ", "ŭ", "Ů", "ů", "Ű", "ű", "Ų",
    "ų", "Ŵ", "ŵ", "Ŷ", "ŷ", "Ÿ", "Ź", "ź", "Ż",
    "ż", "Ž", "ž", "ƒ", "Ƶ", "ǵ", "ȷ", "ˆ", "ˇ",
    "˘", "˙", "˚", "˛", "˜", "˝", "̑", "Α", "Β",
    "Γ", "Δ", "Ε", "Ζ", "Η", "Θ", "Ι", "Κ", "Λ",
    "Μ", "Ν", "Ξ", "Ο", "Π", "Ρ", "Σ", "Τ", "Υ",
    "Φ", "Χ", "Ψ", "Ω", "α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε",
    "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ",
    "ο", "π", "ρ", "ς", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ", "χ",
    "ψ", "ω", "ϑ", "ϒ", "ϕ", "ϖ", "Ϝ", "ϝ", "ϰ",
    "ϱ", "ϵ", "϶", "Ё", "Ђ", "Ѓ", "Є", "Ѕ", "І",
    "Ї", "Ј", "Љ", "Њ", "Ћ", "Ќ", "Ў", "Џ", "А",
    "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й",
    "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т",
    "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы",
    "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я", "а", "б", "в", "г", "д",
    "е", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н",
    "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц",
    "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я",
    "ё", "ђ", "ѓ", "є", "ѕ", "і", "ї", "ј", "љ",
    "њ", "ћ", "ќ", "ў", "џ", "‐", "–", "—", "―",
    "‖", "‘", "’", "‚", "“", "”", "„", "†", "‡",
    "•", "‥", "…", "‰", "‱", "′", "″", "‴", "‵",
    "‹", "›", "‾", "⁁", "⁃", "⁄", "⁏", "⁗", " ",
    "&ThickSpace", "⁠", "⁡", "⁢", "⁣", "€", "⃛", "⃜",
    "ℂ", "℅", "ℊ", "ℋ", "ℌ", "ℍ", "ℎ", "ℏ", "ℐ",
    "ℑ", "ℒ", "ℓ", "ℕ", "№", "℗", "℘", "ℙ", "ℚ",
    "ℛ", "ℜ", "ℝ", "℞", "™", "ℤ", "℧", "ℨ", "℩",
    "ℬ", "ℭ", "ℯ", "ℰ", "ℱ", "ℳ", "ℴ", "ℵ", "ℶ",
    "ℷ", "ℸ", "ⅅ", "ⅆ", "ⅇ", "ⅈ", "⅓", "⅔", "⅕",
    "⅖", "⅗", "⅘", "⅙", "⅚", "⅛", "⅜", "⅝", "⅞",
    "←", "↑", "→", "↓", "↔", "↕", "↖", "↗", "↘",
    "↙", "↚", "↛", "↝", "&nrarrw", "↞", "↟", "↠",
    "↡", "↢", "↣", "↤", "↥", "↦", "↧", "↩", "↪",
    "↫", "↬", "↭", "↮", "↰", "↱", "↲", "↳", "↵",
    "↶", "↷", "↺", "↻", "↼", "↽", "↾", "↿", "⇀",
    "⇁", "⇂", "⇃", "⇄", "⇅", "⇆", "⇇", "⇈", "⇉",
    "⇊", "⇋", "⇌", "⇍", "⇎", "⇏", "⇐", "⇑", "⇒",
    "⇓", "⇔", "⇕", "⇖", "⇗", "⇘", "⇙", "⇚", "⇛",
    "⇝", "⇤", "⇥", "⇵", "⇽", "⇾", "⇿", "∀", "∁",
    "∂", "&npart", "∃", "∄", "∅", "∇", "∈", "∉",
    "∋", "∌", "∏", "∐", "∑", "−", "∓", "∔", "∖",
    "∗", "∘", "√", "∝", "∞", "∟", "∠", "&nang",
    "∡", "∢", "∣", "∤", "∥", "∦", "∧", "∨", "∩",
    "&caps", "∪", "&cups", "∫", "∬", "∭", "∮",
    "∯", "∰", "∱", "∲", "∳", "∴", "∵", "∶", "∷",
    "∸", "∺", "∻", "∼", "&nvsim", "∽", "&race",
    "∾", "&acE", "∿", "≀", "≁", "≂", "&nesim", "≃",
    "≄", "≅", "≆", "≇", "≈", "≉", "≊", "≋", "&napid",
    "≌", "≍", "&nvap", "≎", "&nbump", "≏", "&nbumpe",
    "≐", "&nedot", "≑", "≒", "≓", "≔", "≕", "≖",
    "≗", "≙", "≚", "≜", "≟", "≠", "≡", "&bnequiv",
    "≢", "≤", "&nvle", "≥", "&nvge", "≦", "&nlE", "≧",
    "&NotGreaterFullEqual", "≨", "&lvertneqq", "≩",
    "&gvertneqq", "≪", "&nLtv", "&nLt", "≫",
    "&NotGreaterGreater", "&nGt", "≬", "≭", "≮", "≯",
    "≰", "≱", "≲", "≳", "≴", "≵", "≶", "≷", "≸", "≹",
    "≺", "≻", "≼", "≽", "≾", "≿", "&NotSucceedsTilde",
    "⊀", "⊁", "⊂", "&vnsub", "⊃", "&nsupset", "⊄", "⊅",
    "⊆", "⊇", "⊈", "⊉", "⊊", "&vsubne", "⊋", "&vsupne",
    "⊍", "⊎", "⊏", "&NotSquareSubset", "⊐", "&NotSquareSuperset",
    "⊑", "⊒", "⊓", "&sqcaps", "⊔", "&sqcups", "⊕", "⊖",
    "⊗", "⊘", "⊙", "⊚", "⊛", "⊝", "⊞", "⊟", "⊠", "⊡",
    "⊢", "⊣", "⊤", "⊥", "⊧", "⊨", "⊩", "⊪", "⊫", "⊬",
    "⊭", "⊮", "⊯", "⊰", "⊲", "⊳", "⊴", "&nvltrie", "⊵",
    "&nvrtrie", "⊶", "⊷", "⊸", "⊹", "⊺", "⊻", "⊽", "⊾",
    "⊿", "⋀", "⋁", "⋂", "⋃", "⋄", "⋅", "⋆", "⋇", "⋈",
    "⋉", "⋊", "⋋", "⋌", "⋍", "⋎", "⋏", "⋐", "⋑", "⋒",
    "⋓", "⋔", "⋕", "⋖", "⋗", "⋘", "&nLl", "⋙", "&nGg",
    "⋚", "&lesg", "⋛", "&gesl", "⋞", "⋟", "⋠", "⋡", "⋢",
    "⋣", "⋦", "⋧", "⋨", "⋩", "⋪", "⋫", "⋬", "⋭", "⋮",
    "⋯", "⋰", "⋱", "⋲", "⋳", "⋴", "⋵", "¬indot", "⋶",
    "⋷", "⋹", "¬inE", "⋺", "⋻", "⋼", "⋽", "⋾", "⌅", "⌆",
    "⌈", "⌉", "⌊", "⌋", "⌌", "⌍", "⌎", "⌏", "⌐", "⌒",
    "⌓", "⌕", "⌖", "⌜", "⌝", "⌞", "⌟", "⌢", "⌣", "⌭",
    "⌮", "⌶", "⌽", "⌿", "⍼", "⎰", "⎱", "⎴", "⎵", "⎶",
    "⏜", "⏝", "⏞", "⏟", "⏢", "⏧", "␣", "Ⓢ", "─", "│",
    "┌", "┐", "└", "┘", "├", "┤", "┬", "┴", "┼", "═",
    "║", "╒", "╓", "╔", "╕", "╖", "╗", "╘", "╙", "╚",
    "╛", "╜", "╝", "╞", "╟", "╠", "╡", "╢", "╣", "╤",
    "╥", "╦", "╧", "╨", "╩", "╪", "╫", "╬", "▀", "▄",
    "█", "░", "▒", "▓", "□", "▪", "▫", "▭", "▮", "▱",
    "△", "▴", "▵", "▸", "▹", "▽", "▾", "▿", "◂", "◃",
    "◊", "○", "◬", "◯", "◸", "◹", "◺", "◻", "◼", "★",
    "☆", "☎", "♀", "♂", "♠", "♣", "♥", "♦", "♪", "♭",
    "♮", "♯", "✓", "✗", "✠", "✶", "❘", "❲", "❳", "⟈",
    "⟉", "⟦", "⟧", "⟨", "⟩", "⟪", "⟫", "⟬", "⟭", "⟵",
    "⟶", "⟷", "⟸", "⟹", "⟺", "⟼", "⟿", "⤂", "⤃",
    "⤄", "⤅", "⤌", "⤍", "⤎", "⤏", "⤐", "⤑", "⤒", "⤓",
    "⤖", "⤙", "⤚", "⤛", "⤜", "⤝", "⤞", "⤟", "⤠", "⤣",
    "⤤", "⤥", "⤦", "⤧", "⤨", "⤩", "⤪", "⤳", "&nrarrc",
    "⤵", "⤶", "⤷", "⤸", "⤹", "⤼", "⤽", "⥅", "⥈", "⥉",
    "⥊", "⥋", "⥎", "⥏", "⥐", "⥑", "⥒", "⥓", "⥔", "⥕",
    "⥖", "⥗", "⥘", "⥙", "⥚", "⥛", "⥜", "⥝", "⥞", "⥟",
    "⥠", "⥡", "⥢", "⥣", "⥤", "⥥", "⥦", "⥧", "⥨", "⥩",
    "⥪", "⥫", "⥬", "⥭", "⥮", "⥯", "⥰", "⥱", "⥲", "⥳",
    "⥴", "⥵", "⥶", "⥸", "⥹", "⥻", "⥼", "⥽", "⥾", "⥿",
    "⦅", "⦆", "⦋", "⦌", "⦍", "⦎", "⦏", "⦐", "⦑", "⦒", "⦓",
    "⦔", "⦕", "⦖", "⦚", "⦜", "⦝", "⦤", "⦥", "⦦", "⦧",
    "⦨", "⦩", "⦪", "⦫", "⦬", "⦭", "⦮", "⦯", "⦰", "⦱",
    "⦲", "⦳", "⦴", "⦵", "⦶", "⦷", "⦹", "⦻", "⦼", "⦾",
    "⦿", "⧀", "⧁", "⧂", "⧃", "⧄", "⧅", "⧉", "⧍", "⧎",
    "⧏", "&NotLeftTriangleBar", "⧐", "&NotRightTriangleBar",
    "⧜", "⧝", "⧞", "⧣", "⧤", "⧥", "⧫", "⧴", "⧶", "⨀", "⨁",
    "⨂", "⨄", "⨆", "⨌", "⨍", "⨐", "⨑", "⨒", "⨓", "⨔", "⨕",
    "⨖", "⨗", "⨢", "⨣", "⨤", "⨥", "⨦", "⨧", "⨩", "⨪", "⨭",
    "⨮", "⨯", "⨰", "⨱", "⨳", "⨴", "⨵", "⨶", "⨷", "⨸", "⨹",
    "⨺", "⨻", "⨼", "⨿", "⩀", "⩂", "⩃", "⩄", "⩅", "⩆", "⩇",
    "⩈", "⩉", "⩊", "⩋", "⩌", "⩍", "⩐", "⩓", "⩔", "⩕", "⩖",
    "⩗", "⩘", "⩚", "⩛", "⩜", "⩝", "⩟", "⩦", "⩪", "⩭",
    "&ncongdot", "⩮", "⩯", "⩰", "&napE", "⩱", "⩲", "⩳", "⩴",
    "⩵", "⩷", "⩸", "⩹", "⩺", "⩻", "⩼", "⩽", "&nles", "⩾",
    "&nges", "⩿", "⪀", "⪁", "⪂", "⪃", "⪄", "⪅", "⪆", "⪇",
    "⪈", "⪉", "⪊", "⪋", "⪌", "⪍", "⪎", "⪏", "⪐", "⪑", "⪒",
    "⪓", "⪔", "⪕", "⪖", "⪗", "⪘", "⪙", "⪚", "⪝", "⪞", "⪟",
    "⪠", "⪡", "&NotNestedLessLess", "⪢", "&NotNestedGreaterGreater",
    "⪤", "⪥", "⪦", "⪧", "⪨", "⪩", "⪪", "⪫", "⪬", "&smtes",
    "⪭", "&lates", "⪮", "⪯", "&NotPrecedesEqual", "⪰",
    "&NotSucceedsEqual", "⪳", "⪴", "⪵", "⪶", "⪷", "⪸", "⪹",
    "⪺", "⪻", "⪼", "⪽", "⪾", "⪿", "⫀", "⫁", "⫂", "⫃", "⫄",
    "⫅", "&nsubE", "⫆", "&nsupseteqq", "⫇", "⫈", "⫋", "&vsubnE",
    "⫌", "&varsupsetneqq", "⫏", "⫐", "⫑", "⫒", "⫓", "⫔", "⫕",
    "⫖", "⫗", "⫘", "⫙", "⫚", "⫛", "⫤", "⫦", "⫧", "⫨", "⫩",
    "⫫", "⫬", "⫭", "⫮", "⫯", "⫰", "⫱", "⫲", "⫳", "⫽", "&nparsl",
    "ﬀ", "ﬁ", "ﬂ", "ﬃ", "ﬄ"
];